# Scrapy. How to remove style attribute (class or id attribute) from tags in parsed HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrapy. How to remove style attributes (class or id attributes) from tags in parsed HTML with lxml help? Something like `lxml.html.clean.Cleaner` or something like:

```
for tag in html.xpath('//*[@class]'):
    tag.attrib.pop('class')
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and give an example of what you get (with your current code) and what you want instead?

Comment: I need to have parsed items with tags, not only text. And parsed items a style-full. for example: item['asterisk1'][0] = '<li class="wb-caption-alt wb-dark2-grey wb-super-text wb-sup-script"><sup class="wb-super-script">1</sup>Requires InstantGo or device that passes the device encryption HCK test</li>'

Answer (score 1):

You have to import another builtin python class in the spider file

```
import lxml.html.clean as clean
safe_attrs = set(['src', 'alt', 'href', 'title', 'width', 'height'])
kill_tags = ['object', 'iframe']
cleaner = clean.Cleaner(safe_attrs_only=True, safe_attrs=safe_attrs, kill_tags=kill_tags)
html_string = "some html string with iframes, objects…"
```

and then use it like this

```
cleaned_html = cleaner.clean_html(html_string)
```

You can customize `safe_attrs`, and `kill_tags` to whatever attr and tags you want to remove.